# Laravel 5 Route variable has space

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have some code in a controller called SearchController and I redirect to a route with some variables that were defined. The city variable has the spaces removed and a dash added for when the city has two words(ex:Des Moines). That would return "des-moines". I did this because in the URL it was showing up as "des+monies". But after changing that. The route does seem to know what to do or it breaks. So how can I tell the route that the {city} can also be things like "des-moines" instead of having "des+moines". Or is there a better way of doing this.

Url I want(but breaks and gets error):

```
www.domain.com/des-moines-ia-provider1-50301
```

SearchController(cut down version):

```
$city =  strtolower(preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $data[0]->City));
$state = strtolower($data[0]->State);
$provider = strtolower($data[0]->{'Provider Name'});
$zipcode = $data[0]->{'Zip Code'};  

return redirect()->route('search.provider1',[$city,$state,$zipcode])->with('data',$data);
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('{city}-{state}-provider1-{zipcode}',['uses' => 'PagesController@provider1','as' => 'search.provider1']);
```

Error:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

Comment: That's to be expected, because the router can't know which dash to interpret as the delimiter and it most likely interprets the city being `des` and the state as being `moines`, which leaves an extra `-ia` before `-provider1` that messes up the match. Why not just use slashes instead of dashes? They offer good URL structuring, but in that case I would suggest you switch the state and the city, since the city is part of the state and it makes more sense as hierarchically: `{state}/{city}/provider-1/{zipcode}`, because `www.domain.com/ia/des-moines/provider1/50301` looks just fine.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is replacing in your routes separator that won't be used in in city/state/zipcode.

Maybe:

```
Route::get('{city}/{state}/provider1/{zipcode}',['uses' => 'PagesController@provider1','as' => 'search.provider1']);
```

would be better? I suppose `/` is not used in city/state and zipcode

Comment: I tried doing this but it breaks my views. It cant seem to find the CSS after that. Is there something I should change?